# How is this function printing an integer in binary form?

Tags: c

```
void DecInBinary(unsigned int dec) {                                   
int i = 0;
unsigned int highestOne = 1 << (sizeof(unsigned int)*8 - 1);
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(int)*8; i++)
    printf("%d", (dec & (highestOne >> i))>> (highestOne - i - 1));
}
```

In particular, I don't understand how the second right shift operator in the print statement results in either a '1' or '0'.

Comment: Time to use your [rubber duck debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), or an actual debugger that can step through code statement by statement.  I also suggest you try to simplify the more complex expressions, using temporary variables to store immediate results.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it will not work in this case. Rubber duck operator will have to have a lots of knowledge and experience to explain "why does this code work? (and how)".

Comment: `In particular, I don't understand how the second right shift operator in the print statement results in either a '1' or '0'.` it should not work and works only by accident on x86

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude how can `0x80000000 >> 0x7fffffff` give one in C? Rubber duck will not help with it

Comment: @P__J__ Okay, I'll admit that this specific code is a bad example. I still think it might be a good start (especially the part about making it simpler) and as a generic tip it still have value (which is why I'll leave it).

Answer (score 2):

> How is this function printing an integer in binary form?

The answer is: by accident. Only because you run it on the particular hardware. But from the C point of view it should not.

This an example how to make code hard to read and understand and as a consequence wrong.

`(dec & (highestOne >> i)) >> (highestOne - i - 1))`

`highestOne` starts from a very big number, `highestOne - i - 1` will be larger than the operand size until `highestOne - i - 1` is less than `sizeof(int)*8`. This is an undefined behaviour. So how does this code actually work? It is only because x86 implementation of the `shr` instruction actually shifts by given number of bits modulo size of the operand in bits.  It will not work on most other systems.

I bet that the author (judging from the code) of the original code did it by accident.

The correct code should be (`!!` gives one if number is non zero, zero otherwise):

```
void toBin(unsigned int dec) 
{         
                              
    unsigned int currentMask = 1 << (sizeof(dec) * CHAR_BIT - 1);
    for (; currentMask; currentMask >>= 1)
        printf("%d", !!(dec & currentMask));
    fflush(stdout);
}

int main(void)
{
    unsigned num;
    for(int x = 1; x < 10; x++)
    {   
        num = rand();
        toBin(num); printf(" (%u)\n", num);
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this undefined behavior? Bit-shifting unsigned integers is well-defined, and unsigned overflow and underflow are well-defined. I don't understand what you are saying is undefined, or why.

Comment: why it is greater - read carefully my answer. BTW everything is there also explanation why it is an UB

Comment: If  the  value  of  the  right  operand  is  negative  or is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined. From the C standard 6.5.7

Comment: The code also assumes CHAR_BIT == 8 and that unsigned int has no padding bits.  Both of those shortcomings can be fixed as well.

See this, for example:  https://www.quora.com/How-is-this-function-printing-an-integer-in-binary-form/answer/Joe-Zbiciak

Comment: @JoeZ *`unsigned int has no padding bits`* have you ever seen an `unsigned integer` **with** padding bits?

Comment: @JoeZ  (CHAR_BIT) yes it is from the OPs code and it is not relevant to the problem in this case.

Answer (score -1):

highestOne is a bitmask with a single bit in it.

The dec & ... expression is ANDing that bit mask, so if the bit in that position is preserved and all the others are zeroed out.

The second shift operator, >>, is moving that bit down to the 1s place, causing the number to be only a 0 or a 1 for the %d in the printf() statement.

The for loop is for rinse, lather, and repeating, but for successive positions.

Comment: it does not explain why this code works - but it should not.

Comment: `The second shift operator, >>, is moving that bit down to the 1s place` it is not in C. Did you analyse the code?